# Angular JS send html to data base

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, angularjs

I m sending html < p >hello< /p>

```
<div class="input-field">
 <input id="price" type="number" ng-model="productData.price" ng-init="productData.price = ''" >
  <label for="price">Price</label>
</div>



<div id="editor3" class="ql-container ql-snow">
      <div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true">
        <p>hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="productData.description">
```

to angular js code, But it is not working. I am new to angular js. the fifth line below I thing not taking data from HTML code

```
 $scope.addProdcut = function (productData) {
        if ($scope.validateProduct(productData)) {
            $scope.productLoader = true;
            $('#productSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
$scope.productData.description = $('#editor3 .ql-editor').html() != '' ? $('#editor3 .ql-editor').html() : '';
            var url = webroot + 'products/addProduct';
            $scope.data = {
                "type": "json",
                "data": productData,
                "image": $scope.productImage
            };
            $http.post(url, $scope.data, {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': token
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Controller file

```
public function addProduct()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $content = $this->request->input('json_decode', true);
        $data = $content['data'];
        $file = '';
        if ($content['image'] != '') {
            $file = date('ymd') . time() . '.' . 'jpg';
            $path = WWW_ROOT . 'img/products/' . $file;
            $this->base64_to_jpeg($content['image'], $path);
        }
        $products = TableRegistry::get('Products');
        $query = $products->query()->insert(['item', 'price', 'description', 'image', 'status', 'added_by', 'created'])
            ->values([
                'item' => $data['name'],
                'price' => $data['price'],
                'description' => $data['description'],
                'image' => $file,
                'status' => 1,
                'added_by' => $this->loggedInUser['id'] . '||' . $this->loggedInUser['username'],
                'created' => date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s"),
            ])->execute();
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'success']);
        exit;
    }
}
```

it is a word editor in form, from where I want to save HTML code (from word editor) in data base using a hidden input field. by sending data ng-model to that hidden input field

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the value in `$scope.productData.description`  and then sending `productData`, instead, you should send `$scope.productData.description`.

```
$scope.addProdcut = function(productData) {
  if ($scope.validateProduct(productData)) {
    $scope.productLoader = true;
    $('#productSubmit').attr('disabled', true);
    $scope.productData.description = $('#editor3 .ql-editor').html() != '' ? $('#editor3 .ql-editor').html() : '';
    var url = webroot + 'products/addProduct';
    $scope.data = {
      "type": "json",
      "data": $scope.productData.description,
      "image": $scope.productImage
    };
    $http.post(url, $scope.data, {
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': token
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited a code, check the only description is productData.description similarly other are productData.name, productData.rollno   etc